# RegEx only match numbers that does not start nor end with single quote

Tags: java, regex

Im trying to replace all numbers in a string, that is not wrapped in a single quote using Java.

Example: 22 111' 333

matching should return only: 22 and 333

I have tried several regexes:

I started by selecting all occurences of numbers `-?\\d+`

I tried to build on this, but couldnt negate the single quote
and a combination with the above: `-?(^[^\']([0-9]*))` nor `(^((?!').)[0-9]{1,22})` worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex with look-arounds assertions:

```
(?<![\d'])\d+(?![\d'])
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VOG0G2/1)

- `(?<![\d'])`: Negative Lookbehind to assert we don't have a single quote or digit at previous position
- `(?![\d'])`:  Negative Lookahead to assert we don't have a single quote or digit at next position